# Facebook iOS SDK I changed permissions but login dialog still states old permission

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-ios-sdk

I had this code for my FBLoginView to access permissions:

```
[[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public_profile, email, user_friends"]];
```

Originally we wanted a list of the users friends, but now we don't so...

I changed it to this:

```
[[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public_profile, email"]];
```

However the Facebook dialog still ask for access to the users friends list.

When I got to developer.facebook.com > App > Status and Review I still see user_friends under login permissions with no way to delete or edit this section of my app.

Any thoughts on how to get rid of this permissions setting?

Here's a screenshot

[image: permissions screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

These are the default settings when you create a Facebook app. Anything extra needs to be approved by Facebook.